# Context path configuration in Apache tomcat 8.0.30

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, tomcat8

I currently have an apache tomcat application running on my machine. I need to make this application accessible over an external URL.

I can access the application locally at http://localhost/c. I want to be able to access the application externally at https://example.com/b/001/c. TO achieve this, I made the below change to my conf/server.xml file

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">


  <Context docBase=""  path="/b/001" reloadable="true" />
```

After making this change, my local set up works fine when I test with the below URL

http://localhost/c/1.jsp (works fine)

When I try to  load the external URL (https://example.com/b/001/c/1.jsp)  however, I get the below error

An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file: [......./1_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. a.c.d.e.database.DB resolves to a package

What change should I make to make this publicly available on the external server?

Comment: Did you try using  docBase="c"